# Glitch in eating area in Minecraft mini game

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft on Xbox One, I was in a mini-game waiting area and went into the area where it's a sword code. I went in there and the swords were gone and there were different things that are not normally in Minecraft, then it took me to the Xbox homepage and I had to relaunch my game? What happened?

Comment: Just imagine WolfieRaps on an arqade question: GIMME DA UPVOTES!

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft usually glitches out when there are lots of chunks to load. If it was a big mini-game with lots of chunks to load, it makes sense that it would glitch out.

**In short, there's nothing to worry about. It happens with every game; so just reload it and hope for the best.**

This source might help: [A Simple fix fore Many XBox One Software Problems](http://www.lifewire.com/fix-for-xbox-one-software-problems-3562278)